# Authenticate {unauthorized_client} Egyptian eInvoicing SDK

Tags: php, json, sdk, invoice

I'm trying to send JSON data by php, but show {"error":"unauthorized_client"}

https://sdk.invoicing.eta.gov.eg/ereceiptapi/01-authenticate-pos/

**i used php code and its work on same sdk *invoice* not *receipt* and try on postman work fine and get access_token**

```
$postData = array(
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret
    );

$headerData = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'posserial' => 'PC0RWSX8',
    'pososversion' => 'windows',
    'posmodelframework' => '',
    'presharedkey' => ''
    );

$url = 'https://id.eta.gov.eg/connect/token';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: I am not exactly sure why it is not working for you, but there is a possible problem I see - are you sure the `$headerData` should contain 2 `Content-Type` headers? The Php manual says `If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten. `, so you are probably calling the API with Json `Content-Type`. Shouldn't that be the `x-www-form-urlencoded`? Please, double-check your settings against Postman.

Comment: _"I'm trying to send JSON"_ - cURL will not automatically encode the data you pass for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` according to any Content-Type header you might have specified. You need to encode it as JSON yourself.

Comment: in postman just Encode URL automatically on